# Started implementing .htaccess but when navigating from the reduced URL, when going into a directory it then can't get back

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

So I have included an htaccess file to my server in the root directory and changed all of the ./ I could find set the absolutes.
However, when I search by URL into one of the directories pressing the home button does not take me home. Instead, it appends the index onto the end:

`/website/book/index.php?p=home`
Instead of
`/website/index.php?p=home`

Where have I made a fuddle?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/paperbound/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Is the htaccess used. `https://sitehost/website/book/2` is URL entered and page retrieved which exists as `https://sitehost/website/index.php?p=book&id=2`, clicking navlink to return to `https://sitehost/website/index.php?p=home`, instead places `https://sitehost/website/book/index.php?p=home` into the URL bar and returns an error as the file does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts clearly, could you please do mention what URL you are hitting in browser? and after hitting that url To which url it should change? Thank you.

Comment: So I have been navigating to website/book/2 which is just a random book id, then pressing any of the navlink buttons will try and insert the index.php?p=navlink after book, as opposed to returning to the root directory. I can naviagte to any page just fine by typing in the URL, but the navlink buttons do not work using the non index.php urls

Comment: Sorry its still not clear, could you please do show example like: you are hitting link in browser like: `http://localhost:80/test1/test2/test3` and you want link to be served in backend like: `http://localhost:80/index.php?bla bla bla` like this way it will help us more to help you.

Comment: ```https://sitehost/website/book/2``` is URL entered and page retrieved which exists as ```https://sitehost/website/index.php?p=book&id=2```, clicking navlink to return to ```https://sitehost/website/index.php?p=home```, instead places ```https://sitehost/website/book/index.php?p=home``` into the URL bar and returns an error as the file does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following htaccess rules file. Make sure to keep your `index.php` file is present in website folder and htaccess is present along side with website folder(not inside it).

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
##Enabling rewrite engine here.
RewriteEngine ON
##Checking conditions for non-existing pages here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
##performing internal rewrite here to index.php file.
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$  $1/index.php?p=$2&id=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Cache is always disabled. Moving to use your method does let me access target URLs but still lands me at ```https://sitehost/website/wrong-directory/index.php?p=home``` as opposed to ```https://sitehost/website/index.php?p=home```

Comment: Very nice solution !